# Where to place accent after applying diaeresis?

Tags: poetry, ancient-greek, stress

So I have the following elegiac couplet:

> κεἱ ψυχή τε πέρην ἐπικεῖται, ἔσχατη ἆσσον,
> μεῖνα δ' ἔγωγ’ ἔμπης, ἰσχναΐνων κραδίην.

Theoretically, the latter hemistich in the second verse should have the metric structure _uu _uu _, so that's where the diaeresis is coming from. However, I am not sure where the accent should fall, whether on the α or on the ι. The ω in the last syllable would dictate it should fall on the ι, but upon reading the word `ἰσχναΐνων` out loud (not in the context of the pentameter, of course) it feels wrong. On the other hand, placing it on the α would break major stress rules. What should be done?

Comment: I don't know anything about poetic scansion, but phonologically an acute on a long vowel/diphthong indicates a rising tone on the *second* mora. If it were the α that had the rising tone the diphthong would originally have had a circumflex.

Comment: The accent on ἔσχατη is violating the same rule. (And if TKR guessed correctly that this is your own composition, wouldn't ἆσσον take a genitive? Though it would ruin the meter.)

Answer (score 3):

I'm doubtful that the diaeresis would be used in this way: you can't generally break diphthongs into two short vowels *metri causa*. There are occasional examples in Homer of disyllabic scansion of what in Classical Greek terms would be a diphthong, e.g. ἐύ for εὖ, but those are archaisms, not applications of a productive rule.

That said,  the accentuation with diaeresis would certainly be ἰσχναΐνων, since ἰσχνάϊνων would break a basic rule of Greek accent.

(BTW is this couplet your composition? I can't make sense of the first line -- could you provide a translation?)